# Relationship between norm of a function and its supremum

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, normed-spaces, sobolev-spaces, supremum-and-infimum

Let $u \in H^{1}(\Omega)$ , $0<\tau <1$ and $B_{\tau R}$ the open ball of radius $\tau R$ under what conditions

(I) $||u||_{L^{p}(B_{\tau R})} = \sup\limits_{B_{R}} u$

and

(II) $||u||_{L^{p}(B_{\tau R})} \geq \sup\limits_{B_{R}} u$

?

Here R is a positive number.

My work:

I know that as $B_{\tau R}$ has finite measure, then if $p \to \infty$ $||u||_{L^{p}(B_{\tau R})} \to ||u||_{L^{\infty}(B_{\tau R})}$, but $
||u||_{L^{\infty}(B_{\tau R})}\geq |u(x)|$ a.e.x in $B_{\tau R}$ from here , i don't know continue..

Comment: What is R? Can you please explain what you have already tried and what you think you might need to do. This will help people see where you are stuck and then to help.